# Swift 2.0 and Google Analytics: Use of unresolved identifier "GAI"

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, swift2

I tried with CocoaPods and wound up with this issue after trying for hours and figured it was CocoaPods. Uninstalled CocoaPods and installed the SDK manually and wound up with the same issue.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    GAI.sharedInstance().trackerWithTrackingId("UA-XXXX-Y");
    return true
}
```

This results in the error `Use of unresolved identifier "GAI"`. I have a bridging header that imports the appropriate header files and all the required libraries included in my Build Phases. Please help!

Comment: It appears that the GAI object is available within other classes, but not within the App Delegate. That's weird. I'm new to Swift.

Comment: just as a try, did you import GAI in the App delegate? i mean as Framework. `import GAI`. Maybe the AppDelegate for swift works different.

Comment: `No such module "GAI"` is the response.

Comment: oh, that means the SDK is really not loaded. Such things are strange, i suppose you tried cleaning derived data, close xcode, empty the tradh and try again?

Comment: Duck. That solved it. Cleared derived data and restarted Xcode. Thank you.

Comment: funny :D, thats xcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I just needed to clear my derived data and restart Xcode. Xcode sucks sometimes. Ha. Thank you [Björn Ro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4328374/bj%C3%B6rn-ro).

Comment: great that i could be a help ;)

Comment: Crap. It wasn't throwing errors and now it is again. Same error, unfortunately. For a minute it was allowing me access to GAI with autocompleting and all, no errors. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Never mind! The issue was that there were two bridging headers. I had to add the imports to both and this solved it! Wow.

Comment: oha, why two bridging headers,

Comment: One in the Test target and one in the normal target.